# Values on the top of the bars are not moving along with the bars

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, d3.js, graph

I'm trying to create a bar chart with x-axis scroll and bar values on the top of the bars. The values are displaying but after scrolling x-axis, the values are not moving along with the bars.

I tried by removing the appended text but it's not working.
Here is my complete code: https://codepen.io/sampath-PerOxide/pen/MZBOmG

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<!--<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.5">

       
        <meta name="description" content="">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-gfdkjb5BdAXd+lj+gudLWI+BXq4IuLW5IT+brZEZsLFm++aCMlF1V92rMkPaX4PP" crossorigin="anonymous">


    </head>
    <body>
                        <div class="row ">
                
            <div class="col-md-12 bg-white">
                <div style="float: left;">
            <h5 class="section-heading">Average</h5></div>
                                <div style="float: right;">
                         <select class="form-control" id="opts">
        <option value="ds1">A</option>
        <option value="ds2">B</option>
        <option value="ds3">C</option>
      </select>
          </div>

            <div id="atthbd"></div>

                </div>
            </div>
        <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="d3pie.js"></script>
<!--        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>-->
<!--        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>
        
        <script>
var ds1 = [
{label:"Company Average", value:"20"},
{label:"Banking & Finance", value:"10"},
{label:"Research & Development", value:"40"},
{label:"Design & Innovaon", value:"20"},
{label:"Sales & Marketing", value:"10"},
{label:"Company Average1", value:"20"},
{label:"Banking & Finance1", value:"10"},
{label:"Research & Development1", value:"40"},
{label:"Design & Innovaon1", value:"20"},
{label:"Sales & Marketing1", value:"10"},
{label:"Company Average2", value:"20"},
{label:"Banking & Finance2", value:"10"},
{label:"Research & Development2", value:"40"},
{label:"Design & Innovaon2", value:"20"},
{label:"Sales & Marketing2", value:"10"},
{label:"Company Average3", value:"20"},
{label:"Banking & Finance3", value:"10"},
{label:"Research & Development3", value:"40"},
{label:"Design & Innovaon3", value:"20"},
{label:"Sales & Marketing3", value:"10"},
{label:"Company Average4", value:"20"},
{label:"Banking & Finance4", value:"10"},
{label:"Research & Development4", value:"40"},
{label:"Design & Innovaon4", value:"20"},
{label:"Sales & Marketing4", value:"10"},
{label:"Company Average5", value:"20"},
{label:"Banking & Finance5", value:"10"},
{label:"Research & Development5", value:"40"},
{label:"Design & Innovaon5", value:"20"},
{label:"Sales & Marketing5", value:"10"},

];
 
  var ds2 = [
{label:"Company Average", value:"10"},
{label:"Banking & Finance", value:"30"},
{label:"Research & Development", value:"20"},
{label:"Design & Innovaon", value:"40"},
{label:"Sales & Marketing", value:"10"},
{label:"Company Average1", value:"30"},
{label:"Banking & Finance1", value:"20"},
{label:"Research & Development1", value:"40"},
{label:"Design & Innovaon1", value:"20"},
{label:"Sales & Marketing1", value:"10"},
{label:"Company Average2", value:"20"},
{label:"Banking & Finance2", value:"10"},
{label:"Research & Development2", value:"40"},
{label:"Design & Innovaon2", value:"20"},
{label:"Sales & Marketing2", value:"10"},
{label:"Company Average3", value:"20"},
{label:"Banking & Finance3", value:"10"},
{label:"Research & Development3", value:"40"},
{label:"Design & Innovaon3", value:"20"},
{label:"Sales & Marketing3", value:"10"},
{label:"Company Average4", value:"20"},
{label:"Banking & Finance4", value:"10"},
{label:"Research & Development4", value:"40"},
{label:"Design & Innovaon4", value:"20"},
{label:"Sales & Marketing4", value:"10"},
{label:"Company Average5", value:"20"},
{label:"Banking & Finance5", value:"10"},
{label:"Research & Development5", value:"40"},
{label:"Design & Innovaon5", value:"20"},
{label:"Sales & Marketing5", value:"10"},

];
              var ds3 = [
{label:"Company Average", value:"40"},
{label:"Banking & Finance", value:"10"},
{label:"Research & Development", value:"30"},
{label:"Design & Innovaon", value:"10"},
{label:"Sales & Marketing", value:"20"},
{label:"Company Average1", value:"30"},
{label:"Banking & Finance1", value:"5"},
{label:"Research & Development1", value:"30"},
{label:"Design & Innovaon1", value:"20"},
{label:"Sales & Marketing1", value:"10"},
{label:"Company Average2", value:"20"},
{label:"Banking & Finance2", value:"10"},
{label:"Research & Development2", value:"40"},
{label:"Design & Innovaon2", value:"20"},
{label:"Sales & Marketing2", value:"10"},
{label:"Company Average3", value:"20"},
{label:"Banking & Finance3", value:"10"},
{label:"Research & Development3", value:"40"},
{label:"Design & Innovaon3", value:"20"},
{label:"Sales & Marketing3", value:"10"},
{label:"Company Average4", value:"20"},
{label:"Banking & Finance4", value:"10"},
{label:"Research & Development4", value:"40"},
{label:"Design & Innovaon4", value:"20"},
{label:"Sales & Marketing4", value:"10"},
{label:"Company Average5", value:"20"},
{label:"Banking & Finance5", value:"10"},
{label:"Research & Development5", value:"40"},
{label:"Design & Innovaon5", value:"20"},
{label:"Sales & Marketing5", value:"10"},

];
                    
var margin =  {top: 20, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 40};
var marginOverview = {top: 30, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 40};
var selectorHeight = 40;
var width = 1100 - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom - selectorHeight;
var heightOverview = 80 - marginOverview.top - marginOverview.bottom;

        var svg = d3.select("#atthbd").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom + selectorHeight);
  
var diagram = svg.append("g")
         .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    
          
           function updateLegend(data) { 
            
       
var maxLength = d3.max(data.map(function(d){ return d.label.length}))
var barWidth = maxLength * 7;
var numBars = Math.round(width/barWidth);
var isScrollDisplayed = barWidth * data.length > width;
       

console.log(isScrollDisplayed)
  
var xscale = d3.scale.ordinal()
                .domain(data.slice(0,numBars).map(function (d) { return d.label; }))
                .rangeBands([0, width], .7);

var yscale = d3.scale.linear()
       .domain([0, 40])
              .range([height, 0]);
  
var xAxis  = d3.svg.axis().scale(xscale).orient("bottom");
var yAxis  = d3.svg.axis().scale(yscale).orient("left");
  var tip2 = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-10, 0])
  .html(function(d2) {
    return "<p class='sec-sub-head'>Avg No.of days:" + d2.value + "</p>";
  })
svg.call(tip2);
  
diagram.append("g")
     .attr("class", "x axis")
       .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + height + ")")
       .call(xAxis);
  
diagram.append("g")
       .attr("class", "y axis")
       .call(yAxis)    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
.text("Average No. of days");
/*
*/

  diagram.selectAll("bars")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("text")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return xscale(d.label); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return yscale(d.value) - 5; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.value; });

var bars = diagram.append("g");
  
bars.selectAll("rect")
            .data(data.slice(0, numBars), function (d) {return d.label; })
            .enter().append("rect")
            .attr("class", "bar")
            .attr("x", function (d) { return xscale(d.label); })
            .attr("y", function (d) { return yscale(d.value); })
            .attr("width", xscale.rangeBand())
            .attr("height", function (d) { return height - yscale(d.value); }) 
            .on('mouseover', tip2.show)
            .on('mouseout', tip2.hide)

    ;

                    
if (isScrollDisplayed)
{
  var xOverview = d3.scale.ordinal()
                  .domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.label; }))
                  .rangeBands([0, width], .2);
  yOverview = d3.scale.linear().range([heightOverview, 0]);
  yOverview.domain(yscale.domain());

  var subBars = diagram.selectAll('.subBar')
      .data(data)

  subBars.enter().append("rect")
      .classed('subBar', true)
      .attr({
          height: function(d) {
              return heightOverview - yOverview(d.value);
          },
          width: function(d) {
              return xOverview.rangeBand()
          },
          x: function(d) {

              return xOverview(d.label);
          },
          y: function(d) {
              return height + heightOverview + yOverview(d.value)
          }
      })

  var displayed = d3.scale.quantize()
              .domain([0, width])
              .range(d3.range(data.length));

  diagram.append("rect")
              .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + (height + margin.bottom) + ")")
              .attr("class", "mover")
              .attr("x", 0)
              .attr("y", 0)
              .attr("height", selectorHeight)
              .attr("width", Math.round(parseFloat(numBars * width)/data.length))
              .attr("pointer-events", "all")
              .attr("cursor", "ew-resize")
              .call(d3.behavior.drag().on("drag", display))
    
    ;

     
}
/*
               function createsGrid(data) {
       var grid = gridLine.selectAll("line.horizontalGrid").data(scaleY.ticks());

       grid.enter()
       .append("line")
       .attr("class","horizontalGrid");

       grid.exit().remove();

       grid.attr({
               "x1":0,
               "x2": width,
               "y1": function (d) { return yscale(d); },
               "y2": function (d) { return yscale(d); }
                });
}
*/

function display () {
    var x = parseInt(d3.select(this).attr("x")),
        nx = x + d3.event.dx,
        w = parseInt(d3.select(this).attr("width")),
        f, nf, new_data, rects;

    if ( nx < 0 || nx + w > width ) return;

    d3.select(this).attr("x", nx);

    f = displayed(x);
    nf = displayed(nx);

    if ( f === nf ) return;

    new_data = data.slice(nf, nf + numBars);

    xscale.domain(new_data.map(function (d) { return d.label; }));
    diagram.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);

    rects = bars.selectAll("rect")
      .data(new_data, function (d) {return d.label; });

   rects.attr("x", function (d) { return xscale(d.label); });

//    rects.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + xscale(d.label) + ",0)"; })

    rects.enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function (d) { return xscale(d.label); })
      .attr("y", function (d) { return yscale(d.value); })
      .attr("width", xscale.rangeBand())
      .attr("height", function (d) { return height - yscale(d.value); })
      .on('mouseover', tip2.show)
      .on('mouseout', tip2.hide)

    ;
    
     bars.selectAll("rects")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("text")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return xscale(d.label)})
      .attr("y", function(d) { return yscale(d.value) - 5; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.value; });


/*
  bars.selectAll(".bars")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("text")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return xscale(d.label) + xscale.rangeBand()/2; })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return yscale(d.value) - 5; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.value; });
*/
    
    rects.exit().remove();
};
         
  }
         
            // generate initial legend
updateLegend(ds1);

// handle on click event
d3.select('#opts')
  .on('change', function() {
   $( "svg g" ).empty();
    var data = eval(d3.select(this).property('value'));
    updateLegend(data);
});
            
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can hide the values on the top of the bars when scrolled.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to remove that value on top of bars?

Comment: No, I want to show the values on top of the bars. but after scrolling, the previous values are still displaying and overlapping with current viewing values.

Comment: This is what I'm expecting after x-axis scroll: https://i.imgur.com/b1BkHNG.png

Comment: but this issue doesn't exists in the codepen you provided

Comment: https://codepen.io/sampath-PerOxide/pen/MZBOmG  If you drag x-axis, for example 100px, the bars are moved to left and new bars are shown from the right. when the bars are moved to the left after drag, the values are fixed their and not moving along with the bars.

Comment: The crossed values should be removed after x-axis drag. https://i.imgur.com/b1BkHNG.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind your text labels to the data, in the same way you do for the bars. Then you can update the data of the selection (and the positions & text) in the update function.

```js
var ds1 = [{ label: "Company Average", value: "20" },{ label: "Banking & Finance", value: "10" },{ label: "Research & Development", value: "40" },{ label: "Design & Innovaon", value: "20" },{ label: "Sales & Marketing", value: "10" },{ label: "Company Average1", value: "20" },{ label: "Banking & Finance1", value: "10" },{ label: "Research & Development1", value: "40" },{ label: "Design & Innovaon1", value: "20" },{ label: "Sales & Marketing1", value: "10" },{ label: "Company Average2", value: "20" },{ label: "Banking & Finance2", value: "10" },{ label: "Research & Development2", value: "40" },{ label: "Design & Innovaon2", value: "20" },{ label: "Sales & Marketing2", value: "10" },{ label: "Company Average3", value: "20" },{ label: "Banking & Finance3", value: "10" },{ label: "Research & Development3", value: "40" },{ label: "Design & Innovaon3", value: "20" },{ label: "Sales & Marketing3", value: "10" },{ label: "Company Average4", value: "20" },{ label: "Banking & Finance4", value: "10" },{ label: "Research & Development4", value: "40" },{ label: "Design & Innovaon4", value: "20" },{ label: "Sales & Marketing4", value: "10" },{ label: "Company Average5", value: "20" },{ label: "Banking & Finance5", value: "10" },{ label: "Research & Development5", value: "40" },{ label: "Design & Innovaon5", value: "20" },{ label: "Sales & Marketing5", value: "10" }];
var ds2 = [{ label: "Company Average", value: "10" },{ label: "Banking & Finance", value: "30" },{ label: "Research & Development", value: "20" },{ label: "Design & Innovaon", value: "40" },{ label: "Sales & Marketing", value: "10" },{ label: "Company Average1", value: "30" },{ label: "Banking & Finance1", value: "20" },{ label: "Research & Development1", value: "40" },{ label: "Design & Innovaon1", value: "20" },{ label: "Sales & Marketing1", value: "10" },{ label: "Company Average2", value: "20" },{ label: "Banking & Finance2", value: "10" },{ label: "Research & Development2", value: "40" },{ label: "Design & Innovaon2", value: "20" },{ label: "Sales & Marketing2", value: "10" },{ label: "Company Average3", value: "20" },{ label: "Banking & Finance3", value: "10" },{ label: "Research & Development3", value: "40" },{ label: "Design & Innovaon3", value: "20" },{ label: "Sales & Marketing3", value: "10" },{ label: "Company Average4", value: "20" },{ label: "Banking & Finance4", value: "10" },{ label: "Research & Development4", value: "40" },{ label: "Design & Innovaon4", value: "20" },{ label: "Sales & Marketing4", value: "10" },{ label: "Company Average5", value: "20" },{ label: "Banking & Finance5", value: "10" },{ label: "Research & Development5", value: "40" },{ label: "Design & Innovaon5", value: "20" },{ label: "Sales & Marketing5", value: "10" }];
var ds3 = [{ label: "Company Average", value: "40" },{ label: "Banking & Finance", value: "10" },{ label: "Research & Development", value: "30" },{ label: "Design & Innovaon", value: "10" },{ label: "Sales & Marketing", value: "20" },{ label: "Company Average1", value: "30" },{ label: "Banking & Finance1", value: "5" },{ label: "Research & Development1", value: "30" },{ label: "Design & Innovaon1", value: "20" },{ label: "Sales & Marketing1", value: "10" },{ label: "Company Average2", value: "20" },{ label: "Banking & Finance2", value: "10" },{ label: "Research & Development2", value: "40" },{ label: "Design & Innovaon2", value: "20" },{ label: "Sales & Marketing2", value: "10" },{ label: "Company Average3", value: "20" },{ label: "Banking & Finance3", value: "10" },{ label: "Research & Development3", value: "40" },{ label: "Design & Innovaon3", value: "20" },{ label: "Sales & Marketing3", value: "10" },{ label: "Company Average4", value: "20" },{ label: "Banking & Finance4", value: "10" },{ label: "Research & Development4", value: "40" },{ label: "Design & Innovaon4", value: "20" },{ label: "Sales & Marketing4", value: "10" },{ label: "Company Average5", value: "20" },{ label: "Banking & Finance5", value: "10" },{ label: "Research & Development5", value: "40" },{ label: "Design & Innovaon5", value: "20" },{ label: "Sales & Marketing5", value: "10" }];

var margin = { top: 20, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 40 };
var marginOverview = { top: 30, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 40 };
var selectorHeight = 40;
var width = 1100 - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom - selectorHeight;
var heightOverview = 80 - marginOverview.top - marginOverview.bottom;

var svg = d3
  .select("#atthbd")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom + selectorHeight);

var diagram = svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

function updateLegend(data) {
  var maxLength = d3.max(
    data.map(function(d) {
      return d.label.length;
    })
  );
  var barWidth = maxLength * 7;
  var numBars = Math.round(width / barWidth);
  var isScrollDisplayed = barWidth * data.length > width;

  var xscale = d3.scale
    .ordinal()
    .domain(
      data.slice(0, numBars).map(function(d) {
        return d.label;
      })
    )
    .rangeBands([0, width], 0.7);

  var yscale = d3.scale
    .linear()
    .domain([0, 40])
    .range([height, 0]);

  var xAxis = d3.svg
    .axis()
    .scale(xscale)
    .orient("bottom");
  var yAxis = d3.svg
    .axis()
    .scale(yscale)
    .orient("left");
  var tip2 = d3
    .tip()
    .attr("class", "d3-tip")
    .offset([-10, 0])
    .html(function(d2) {
      return "<p class='sec-sub-head'>Avg No.of days:" + d2.value + "</p>";
    });
  svg.call(tip2);

  diagram
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

  diagram
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Average No. of days");

  var bartext = diagram
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "bar-texts")
    .selectAll(".bar-text")
    .data(data.slice(0, numBars));

  var barTextEnter = bartext
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "bar-text")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return xscale(d.label);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return yscale(d.value) - 5;
    })
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.value;
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle");

  var bars = diagram.append("g").attr("class", "bars");

  bars
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(data.slice(0, numBars), function(d) {
      return d.label;
    })
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return xscale(d.label);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return yscale(d.value);
    })
    .attr("width", xscale.rangeBand())
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return height - yscale(d.value);
    })
    .on("mouseover", tip2.show)
    .on("mouseout", tip2.hide);

  if (isScrollDisplayed) {
    var xOverview = d3.scale
      .ordinal()
      .domain(
        data.map(function(d) {
          return d.label;
        })
      )
      .rangeBands([0, width], 0.2);
    yOverview = d3.scale.linear().range([heightOverview, 0]);
    yOverview.domain(yscale.domain());

    var subBars = diagram
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "sub-bars")
      .selectAll(".subBar")
      .data(data);

    subBars
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .classed("subBar", true)
      .attr({
        height: function(d) {
          return heightOverview - yOverview(d.value);
        },
        width: function(d) {
          return xOverview.rangeBand();
        },
        x: function(d) {
          return xOverview(d.label);
        },
        y: function(d) {
          return height + heightOverview + yOverview(d.value);
        }
      });

    var displayed = d3.scale
      .quantize()
      .domain([0, width])
      .range(d3.range(data.length));

    diagram
      .append("rect")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + (height + margin.bottom) + ")")
      .attr("class", "mover")
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", 0)
      .attr("height", selectorHeight)
      .attr("width", Math.round(parseFloat(numBars * width) / data.length))
      .attr("pointer-events", "all")
      .attr("cursor", "ew-resize")
      .call(d3.behavior.drag().on("drag", display));
  }

  function display() {
    var x = parseInt(d3.select(this).attr("x")),
      nx = x + d3.event.dx,
      w = parseInt(d3.select(this).attr("width")),
      f,
      nf,
      new_data,
      rects;

    if (nx < 0 || nx + w > width) return;

    d3.select(this).attr("x", nx);

    f = displayed(x);
    nf = displayed(nx);

    if (f === nf) return;

    new_data = data.slice(nf, nf + numBars);

    xscale.domain(
      new_data.map(function(d) {
        return d.label;
      })
    );
    diagram.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);

    rects = bars.selectAll("rect").data(new_data, function(d) {
      return d.label;
    });

    rects.attr("x", function(d) {
      return xscale(d.label);
    });

    rects
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return xscale(d.label);
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return yscale(d.value);
      })
      .attr("width", xscale.rangeBand())
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return height - yscale(d.value);
      })
      .on("mouseover", tip2.show)
      .on("mouseout", tip2.hide);

    bartext
      .data(new_data)
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return xscale(d.label);
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return yscale(d.value) - 5;
      })
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.value;
      });

    bartext.exit().remove();
    rects.exit().remove();
  }
}

// generate initial legend
updateLegend(ds1);

// handle on click event
d3.select("#opts").on("change", function() {
  $("svg g").empty();
  var data = eval(d3.select(this).property("value"));
  updateLegend(data);
});
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 bg-white">
    <div style="float: left;">
      <h5 class="section-heading">Average</h5>
    </div>
    <div style="float: right;">
      <select class="form-control" id="opts"><option value="ds1">A</option><option value="ds2">B</option><option value="ds3">C</option></select>
    </div>
    <div id="atthbd"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/k-sav/pen/XOreVK)